# How do I change the location of a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Can I change the x and y position of a canvas element in Javascript without using CSS?  I cannot seem to find anyone who even asks it on the Internet.

EDIT: Can it be done in HTML?

```
<html>
<title>Testing</title>
    <canvas id="main" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid     #c3c3c3;">
    Error: Browser does not support canvas element.
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        var main = document.getElementById("main");
        var render = main.getContext("2d");
        main.width = 200;
        main.height = 200;
        main.style.left = 100x;
        main.style.top = 100px;
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps describe what you are trying to achieve and why. That will allow a better quality of answer.

Comment: I want to set the position (x, y) of the canvas element in the window in Google Chrome. Is there any code I could use to do this?

Comment: Do you mean without using top and left css properties? By the way why don't you want to use css?

Comment: Because I want to know if it is possible to be done in Javascript alone.

Comment: Yes it is, but it serves no purpose. JavaScript is not for aligning your DOM elements. That's why we have CSS.

Comment: How do I create a canvas element in CSS and load it into a variable in the Javascript? (Sorry, I am new)

Comment: Are you asking how to shift the coordinate of where you start drawing to your Canvas? That's done via the translate method... not sure if that's what you're actually asking.

Comment: I think the problem here is that your question is wrong. Please elaborate a bit by editing the question.

Comment: I am asking, how do I position the canvas differently than where it is normally in the top-right corner.  Is there a way to set the x and y position of the canvas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<html>
<title>Testing</title>
    <canvas id="main" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid     #c3c3c3;">
    Error: Browser does not support canvas element.
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var main = document.getElementById("main");
        var render = main.getContext("2d");
        main.width = 200;
        main.height = 200;
        main.style.left = "100px";
        main.style.top = "100px";
        main.style.position = "absolute";
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I posted my code implementing this above.  It does not seem to work.

Comment: What is the value of the position property of the canvas? Add canvas.style.position = 'absolute'?

Comment: I am declaring the canvas as I am above.  I am not using css.  Look at the code I posted above.

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler What you pasted as your code in the question does not have quote marks around the positions, making illegal JavaScript. (Look in your Error Console, you'll see a syntax error.)

Comment: just FYI if you want to set this with a variable (like I did) you have to make a string    main.style.left = somevar+"px";

Answer (score 2):

CSS is used to manage the properties that, among other things, position elements on the page. If you choose not to define a top or left property in the CSS file or in an inline style, you can still set those properties after the canvas is loaded in the DOM using Javascript. However, all you'd be doing with the script is directly altering the same properties that CSS already manages.

There is no technical advantage to using JS to alter properties in lieu of a stylesheet or inline style, unless you're changing it dynamically after the page has already loaded content with the default styles. If you're looking to do animation, check out [jQuery](http://jquery.org) for a really nice, cross-browser solution for DOM animation. There is already an answer posted for the basic code to set position once using JS, which as I said is a role best reserved for CSS.

Comment: How do I go about doing this in Javascript then?

Comment: Looks like someone else beat me to the JS, heh.